# problema con las tildes en las palabras MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Tengo un problema con las tildes en las palabras que se ven de esta manera: Espa�a Jap�n El cotejamiento que tengo asignado es utf8_spanish2_ci
Versión del servidor: 5.5.62 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
varchar para la columna de la tabla. Se ven las palabras acentuadas de esa manera:
Qué tipo de cotejamiento es el adecuado para que las palabras acentuadas se vean correctamente en castellano?
Se ve mal en las vistas. Ahora de momento hasta que  encuentre  la solución, por ejemplo si pongo inglés lo pongo así `Ingl&#233;s`

Dentro de head

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: El cotejamiento parece adecuado. La pregunta es, ¿dónde se ven así? ¿estás seguro que están bien almacenados?

Answer (score 3):

Pero depende donde tengas el error, en la base o en las vistas?

Por ejemplo en mi caso, para las bases uso el collage **utf8mb4_general_ci** que es el que por defecto me da MySQL. El que tu usas no está mal, pueda que sea por otra cosa, sigamos.

Luego de eso, en la conexión uso el **charset utf8** así `set_charset('utf8')`

Para MySQLi

```
<?php
    // Orientado a Objetos (la mejor en mi opinión)
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        exit();
    }

    echo "Charset es: " . $mysqli->character_set_name();

    // Change character set to utf8
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    echo "Nuevo Charset es: " . $mysqli->character_set_name();

    $mysqli->close();

    // Por Procedimientos
    $enlace = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

    /* verificar la conexión */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* cambiar el conjunto de caracteres a utf8 */
    if (!mysqli_set_charset($enlace, "utf8")) {
        printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($enlace));
    } else {
        printf("Conjunto de caracteres actual: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($enlace));
    }

    mysqli_close($enlace);
?>
```

Para PDO

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",  $user, $password);
    $dbh->exec("set names utf8mb4");

    // O También con
    $connect = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", 
        $user, 
        $pass, 
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        )
    );
```

Y finalmente en las vistas también

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

De ese modo no tendrías porque tener problemas.